# Why did Run best_estimator_ from GridSearch using cross-validation produce different accuracy score?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation, grid-search

Basically, I want to perform binary classification using SVM (SVC) from sk-learn. Since I do not have separate training and testing data, I use cross-validation to evaluate the effectiveness of the feature set that I use.

Then, I use GridSearchCV to find the best estimator and set the cross-validation parameter to 10. Because I want to analyze the prediction result, I use the best estimator to perform cross-validation using the same dataset (of course I use 10-fold cross-validation).

However, when I print the scores of performance (precision, recall, f-measure, and accuracy), It produces different scores. Why do you think this happen?

I am wondering, in sk-learn should I specify the label for positive one? In my dataset, I have already labelled the positive case as 1.

Lastly, the following text is the snippet for my code.

```
tuned_parameters = [{'kernel': ['linear','rbf'], 'gamma': [1e-5, 1e-4, 1e-3, 1e-2, 1e-1, 1, 10],  'C': [0.1, 1, 5, 10, 50, 100, 1000]}]
scoring = ['f1_macro', 'precision_macro', 'recall_macro', 'accuracy']
clf = GridSearchCV(svm.SVC(), tuned_parameters, cv=10, scoring= scoring, refit='f1_macro')
clf.fit(feature, label)
param_C = clf.cv_results_['param_C']
param_gamma = clf.cv_results_['param_gamma']
P = clf.cv_results_['mean_test_precision_macro']
R = clf.cv_results_['mean_test_recall_macro']
F1 = clf.cv_results_['mean_test_f1_macro']
A = clf.cv_results_['mean_test_accuracy']
#print clf.best_estimator_
print clf.best_score_
scoring2 = ['f1', 'precision', 'recall', 'accuracy']
scores = cross_validate(clf.best_estimator_, feature, label, cv=n, scoring=scoring2, return_train_score=True)
print scores
scores_f1 = np.mean(scores['test_f1'])
scores_p = np.mean(scores['test_precision'])
scores_r = np.mean(scores['test_recall'])
scores_a = np.mean(scores['test_accuracy'])
print '\t'.join([str(scores_f1), str(scores_p), str(scores_r),str(scores_a)])
```

Comment: I've not used `return_train_score=True` before. Are you sure you are finding the mean of your test score and not your train score/both scores? How different are you results?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. 
return_train_score=True is basically returning the evaluation score in training set (in cross-validation). The output from cross_validate function is a dictionary. By default, the test score and train score are stored using different keys in that dictionary. So, changing that parameter does not change the situation. (To confirm this, I also have tried to set that parameter to false, but the results still different).  f1 from GridSearch is 0.5244938753, while from cross-validation is 0.448441558442.

Comment: @kidright, what is `n` (`cv=n`) in your code?

Comment: @MaxU, I use n equals to 10 (integer), so according to my understanding from the documentation, both methods will perform stratified 10-fold cross-validation. Btw, the number of positive case is 41, and negative one is 52.

Comment: How big is your data set? I wouldn't expect such a high discrepancy...

Comment: My dataset is small. So, my dataset have 93 cases, and I have 6 feature items.

Comment: Can you show us the output from `scores['test_accuracy']`? Are you seeing a large variation in accuracy/other metrics? And how many data points in each class?

Comment: @kidright, it could be because of pretty small data set - it's difficult to say not being able to see the data set itself...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be due to that the cross-validation splits used in `cross_validate` and `GridSearchCV` are different, due to the randomness. The effect of this randomness becomes even larger as your dataset is very small (93) and the number of folds is so large (10). A possible fix is to feed into `cv` a fix train/test splits, and reduce the number of folds to reduce the variance, i.e.

```
kfolds=StratifiedKFold(n_splits=3).split(feature, label)
...
clf = GridSearchCV(..., cv=kfolds, ...)
...
scores = cross_validate(..., cv=kfolds, ...)
```

Comment: Yes. it looks like that the split in GridSearchCV and cross_validate is different. In my case, I also set the random_state variable. Thus, the fold becomes: kfolds=StratifiedKFold(n_splits=n, random_state=y, shuffle=True)

Thanks.